# Installing Ubuntu aside OS X and Windows

Tags: macos, bootcamp, unix, windows

My current config is this- I have OS X Mavericks 10.9.2 and Windows 8.1 installed via Boot Camp.
I'd like to install Ubuntu too on my mac- I figured I could do it with rEFInd? Or does the Boot Camp not allow this sort of stuff? How should I proceed with Installation?

Thanks!

Comment: You might want to look for tripleboot in the searchbox, I've seen this question before.

Comment: As @rob already noted there is a number of similar questions about this already. Please have a look at the answers given there but feel free to come back and edit the things you've tried and the result you got into the question if you can't get it to work. We then can reopen the question for you.